# GIMP how to remove level from nested level

Tags: gimp, optimization

I want to un nested (I know that this words is not correct) a level:

I have:

```
level1
    level 2
    level 2
```

I would have:

```
level 2
level 2
```

Is it possible?
How can I obtain it?

---

this layer is the one that contain the other nested layer. But it it empty
I can for sure erase it. 
But I need to erase it without the other nested layer it contains

Comment: Can't you take a screen capture to show what you want? It might help.

Comment: "Layer", maybe? You want to remove a layer (or two, in your example) from a layer group, I assume. And I guess it isn't just two of them, because you would just have done this in less time than writing this question :)

Comment: If you are trying to move layers out of a layer group, you can just left click and drag them out of the layer group. That *sounds* like your issue, but the question isn't really a clear. A screenshot would help.

Answer (score 2):

## Drag each layer out of the layer group

Layers actually can't be nested in GIMP. What you are seeing is a [layer group](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-groups.html), which is just a container to help organize layers and perform some actions on all of them at once.

Click and drag a layer to move it in an out of a layer group, just like you would normally rearrange layers.

If you are looking for a quick way to delete the layer group container but keep the layers that are in it and promote them up a level, I don't believe that's possible. You'll need to move each layer one at a time.

If you don't care about preserving individual layers, you could alternatively flatten the layer group, which will merge them all into one layer.